# Bind $index to ng-model in angular-ui-select

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-select

I was trying to bind `$index` to `ng-model` using `ui-select` directive but no luck.

```
<ui-select ng-model="selected.m">
    <ui-select-match>
      <span ng-bind="$select.selected.name"></span>
    </ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="$index as choice in itemArray">
      <span ng-bind="choice + '' + $index"></span>
    </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>
```

In above template `itemArray` is an array of month names and upon selecting any month from the drop-down list I want to bind its `$index` to the `ng-model` (ie. 'selected.m') .

I've made [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/zw6DrzaXOgrKiuR3fCTn?p=preview) plunker ready.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way around this :

```
  <ui-select ng-model="dummy"  ng-change="selected.m=itemArray.indexOf(dummy)">
    <ui-select-match>
      <span ng-bind="$select.selected.name"></span>
    </ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="choice in itemArray">
      <span ng-bind="choice + '/' + $index"></span>
    </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>
```

This is necessary because $index is only available in the track by of the expression or inside the loop. Furthermore AngularJS is a framework that want you to manipulate objects and not index like the old time, this is why i think ng-repeat/ng-options wasn't design to do this.

Comment: Nice work around,  but lets see if someone comes with some solution :-)

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is the $index then you can do this:

```
<ui-select-choices repeat="$index in itemArray">
  <span ng-bind="itemArray[$index] + '' + $index"></span>
</ui-select-choices>
```

This sets the $select.selected to the $index which is what updates your ng-model.

```
<pre> {{ selected }} </pre>

<ui-select ng-model="selected.m">
  <ui-select-match>
    <span>{{$select.selected}}</span>
  </ui-select-match>
  <ui-select-choices repeat="$index in itemArray">
    <span ng-bind="itemArray[$index] + '' + $index"></span>
  </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ui-select ng-model="vm.mySelectedCountry" title="Choose a country" ng-required="true"> 
        <ui-select-match placeholder="">{{vm.countries[vm.mySelectedCountry].countryName}}</ui-select-match>
        <ui-select-choices repeat="$index in vm.countries| filter: $select.search">
                <span ng-bind-html="vm.countries[$index].countryName | highlight: $select.search"></span>
        </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```